# Python: virtual enviroments using the same modules

Tags: macos, python-venv

I have 10 virtual enviroments for 10 diferent projects, but they have in common many requirements.
For example: let say all use `pandas`.

Question 1: this mean I have 10 `pandas` pip downloaded occuping storage?

Question 2: for this commonly used requierments wouldn't be a better solution to install at system level ("base")? how do you do this?

Question 3: Is it a crazy idea to create a virtual enviroment with this libraries and use it as a "base" and then set `include-system-site-packages = true` in `pyvenv.cfg`?

What are the good practices?

I'm on macOS and use hombrew python.

Thanks in advance for your insights and experience.

Comment: I don't know an ideal solution for this, but I do know a convenient one. Create a public GitHub repository and create a `requirements.txt` file with all the necessary installations needed. Then just activate the virtual environments on your command line one by one (if not too many) and then clone this repository and use `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a docker container for your common packages, and then you just need to apply whatever you are doing on top of that image. Yes you will have 10 images, but only 1 image with pandas for example.
So to answer your questions...

Question 1, yes.
Question 2, check docker and start using it.
Question 3, in line with question 2 if you use docker.